How to write the edge of the shape?
I'm wondering what the edge notation of a geometric shape F is like. I've also been told that it can be written ∂F (with the same symbol as the partial derivative), is this correct?

The common names are "boundary" and "frontier", not "edge". The terminology "shape" also means something else, one usually refers to "subsets." Please edit your question to state your source (e.g. was it a professor, a student, a random guy in a bar...). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)
